# Would it be possible to render an image in a Twitter Bootstrap popover?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here's how the popover is called http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#popovers

Based off of the page you can only put text in it as far as I can tell

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can load HTML instead of text content and enable html option when you initialize your popover.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gyRGS/

## Html

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content="<img src='https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3088494582/6a119c4f95d572c91b8393fd96ddc785.jpeg' />">Click to toggle popover</a>
```

## Javascript

```
$('.btn-danger').popover({
    html: true
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's just HTML. Did you try an image?

Note that you might need to HTML encode your markup, maybe even twice so that it's still HTML when it's decoded.

Comment: Here's the link that calls the popover:

<a href="#" class="key btn" data-toggle="popover" title content='+key_content+' data-original-title="Key">key</a>

I have it in javascript so I can append it to another jQuery plugin. But, the 'key_content' is what goes into the popover. The problem is that when I set it equal to anything besides text the popover won't accept it.